# Move semantics vs pimpl

Tags: c++, c++14, signals-slots

I'm writing a generic pure C++14 implementation of a `signal` class, with lifetime tracking of the connected objects, and an additional plus that all this works with copy and move operations.

There are three types of implementations I have now discovered are possible:

1. Use a global `connection_manager` that, well, manages all connections. This would be terrible in a highly concurrent scenario where many signals and slots are connected and disconnected, and would need fine-tuned locking to alleviate some of these issues.
2. Each signal stores its connections, and proper move and copy semantics are implemented. This has two disadvantages: the signal object is large, and move operations are expensive (all the connections need to be updated when the signal or the connectee is moved. This burdens both sides to have proper move constructors.
3. Each signal stores a pointer to the real signal. This extra level of indirection makes moves a lot cheaper, as the real connected object stays put in memory behind the extra level of indirection. Same goes for the connectee, although each signal emission will need to dereference one extra pointer to get the real object. No move semantics need to be implemented explicitly.

Currently, I almost have version 2 ready. I don't know exactly what Qt does, but I know it covers almost everything I want to be able to do with signals/slots, albeit no copy/move semantics and a pre-compilation step.

Am I missing something or is number three the best way to go in the end if I don't want to have a huge impact on users of signals (*i.e.* I don't want to increase the size and complexity of their classes just because my signal/connectee classes do a lot of work each time they're moved/copied.

Note I am looking for real-world experience and suggestions, not opinions.

Comment: "every problem in computer science can be solved with an additional level of indirection - apart from too many levels of indirection"

Comment: #3 appears to be a better solution in principle, but is your current solution "good enough" in practise?  You can only tell that by measuring..

Comment: I think *move semantics* are well designed for **#3** where you have an object that manages a relatively large resource via a pointer. If you are dealing with only *values* then a *move* is no better than a *copy*.

Comment: @Martin: Well, a `property<int>` object that signals its data has changed would become quite large if the object contained a bunch of `std::list` etc to hold its connections. I think it might be surprising to the user to see that his objects have non-proportionally increased in size due to using my `property`. But then the extra indirection impacts the function call speed somewhat. I guess it's a trade-off. Perhaps I can make it into a template parameter so the user can choose if needed.

Comment: #2 is the case why QObjects are not movable. There are simply too many pointers involved that would need to be updated, and it's probably impossible to do in a general case.

Comment: "all the connections need to be updated when the signal or the connectee is moved". This should be a red flag, a clear signal that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: How many signals/slots are we talking about, and how "saturated" are they?  (How many listeners per broadcaster, including the possibility of 0?)  In something like a widely used UI library, you might have 100 broadcasters in one UI widget of which an average of 1 is connected to anything (MS C# UI library, for example), for 1% saturation.  In bespoke use, you might not create a broadcaster unless someone was using it, for saturation nearer 100% or even more than 100%.  Undescribed details like this would change the "right" answer massively.

Comment: @peppe It's far from impossible to do in a general case, just non-trivial. The problem in Qt's implementation is their old connect syntax which doesn't keep enough information to do it. If they abolished that, it should be possible.

Comment: It's not "just" that. Many things in Qt work by keeping raw pointers to various OQbjects. If you make QObjects movable, how do you update all those pointers?

Comment: @peppe Can you give examples of those other things? I'm interested in knowing what they are so I can avoid them ;).

Comment: In my experience, listeners that are just `std::function`s in a smart pointer solve most problems.  You want move semantics; in this model, it would translate to `std::function`s which have "state" arguments that is auto-reseated when the state object moves?  Ie, have you considered splitting the two problems into two problems?

Comment: @Yakk `std::function`s don't have enough information to copy member function connections Nor are they as efficient as storing the actual type of member function pointer. But splitting up the problem is not a bad idea.

Comment: @rubenvb: anywhere, really. Just open a QObject subclass header and see how it manages sub-QObjects, which point to other QObjects, etc.; all kept by raw pointers. For instance, look at the layout system.